# Обход блокировки по IP на ресурсе

Tags: c#

Добрый день. 
Суть моей задачи:

1. есть некий ресурс, с которого необходимо скачивать over 20 тыс. файлов за сутки
2. есть прокси на 10 IP
3. с 10 IP я могу скачать 600-700 файлов (в зависимости от размера) за 25-30 минут (файлы по 100-500 Кб)
4. через эти самые 25-30 минут все 10 IP банятся на 1 час

Как итог:

1. за сутки я могу выкачать около 12 тыс. файлов
2. существует вероятность, что могут забанить не на 1 час, а более, или много более

Суть вопроса к сообществу:

- как можно программно шифровать свой IP?
- есть ли какое-нибудь программное решение (библиотека, ресурс)?
- можно ли для моих целей использовать, например, 10 модемов (у них вроде IP динамический выдается АТС), раз в 10 минут программно их переподключать, чтобы получать новый IP?
- можно как-то заюзать в моих целях браузер Opera(у них есть встроенный VPN)? Есть ли какие-нибудь библиотеки, для использования вместо стандартного WebBrowser компонента на основе оперы? И если есть такой компонент, то можно ли в нем заюзать программно VPN?

P.S: прикупить подсеть на штук 200 IP и юзать их, как прокси, не вариант - текущие 10 не особо охотно дали, а про 200 и говорить смысла нет. И, даже если и будет такая подсеть, то всегда будет вероятность, что все 200 IP будут со временем забанены и подсеть можно будет выкинуть

Использую для работы VS10 C#

Comment: может проще обратиться к разработчикам ресурса с просьбой предоставить api?

Comment: @Grundy пробовали, это было первой мыслью, чтобы напрямую без костылей, но у них нет API, или не хотят делиться

Comment: Так а разработчики что ответили? или обращения не было?

Comment: @Grundy Ответили, что API нет у них, и что нефиг скачивать все подряд, тогда и банить не будут. Но, к сожалению, начальство просит качать все, а не только то, что нужно - мало ли пригодится.

Comment: Программно шифровать свой IP - это ИМХО есть IP spoofing (подмена IP), один из хакерских или околохакерских методов. В зависимости от того, какая у них стоит система защиты, это может и не помочь. Если вы найдете провайдера, который динамически выделяет адреса и часто их меняет, возможно. Что касается Opera (или любого другого браузера), там там ИМХО придется серьезно поработать (разве что написать плагин или расширешение к браузеру). Также можно пощупать TOR (механизм примерно такой же, как при работе с браузером).

Comment: @Sky, соболезную. Крайне рекомендую в таких случаях зафиксировать письменно (в email переписке обычно), ваше мнение что это крайне хреновая идея.  Чтобы потом когда начнут разбирать полеты "почему все так плохо" было что предъявить.

Comment: Есть такая вещь как tor, посмотрите в её сторону.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Нет.** Это "обратный адрес". Если вы хотите получить ответ, вы вынуждены использовать какой-нибудь адрес, ответы на который вы можете каким-то образом получить (напрямую или проксируя).
2. **Есть**, и много, в основном оформлены в виде проксей с какими-то стандартными для прокси интерфейсами. Но стоят денег в зависимости от требований к скорости получения данных (косвенно, это может быть число проксей, объём скачанных данных или число запросов в месяц).
3. **Теоретически**, до момента, пока провайдер не получит жалобу, не отследит её до вас и не приостановит оказание вам услуг связи. Это при условии, что на том конце попросту не забанят всю подсеть, что вообще-то опасно для общедоступных сервисов, но в крайних случаях бывает и такое.
4. **См. п. 3**, + он медленный.

Comment: Спасибо за подробный ответ! По поводу п. 4 - в опере vpn предоставляется самой оперой же, как тогда могут забанить? Да и вопрос скорости при скачивании файлов размером преимущественно 100к не столь важен, если, конечно, 1 такой файл не будет секунд 5 качаться. Не подскажете, где можно посмотреть какие-нибудь библиотеки/компоненты для работы с оперой? На блогах оперы не нашел упоминаний какого-нибудь API для работы из .net.

Comment: @Sky 4. Так VPN же тоже адреса не из ниоткуда берёт. IP-адреса Оперы и забанят. [С Оперой можно работать через Selenium](https://dev.opera.com/blog/operadriver-now-a-part-of-selenium-and-experimental-android-support-2/), например.